# js toggle for multiple divs

Tags: javascript, toggle

I have 3 `div` which are hidden by default. I want to create a toggle for these 3 but I don't want to create `onclick` for each div and add this to the js file:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

I tried creating this scenario with clicked_id but it failed. When I click on the third div, the second one views aswell.

```
var projectEen = document.getElementById("projectInhoud");
projectEen.style.display = "none";
var projectTwee = document.getElementById("projectInhoudTwee");
projectTwee.style.display = "none";
var projectDrie = document.getElementById("projectInhoudDrie");
projectDrie.style.display = "none";

function displayFunction(clicked_id) {
    if (clicked_id == 1) {
        projectEen.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        projectTwee.style.display = "block";
    }  if(clicked_id == 3) {
        projectDrie.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      projectTwee.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

How can I use the first code but to display all 3 div without creating the function 3 times?

EDIT: 
My html

```
     <div id="1" onclick="displayFunction(this.id)" class="projectTitel">
        <h1>Project: a</h1>
     </div>
  <div id="projectInhoudEen" class="projectInhoud"> content </div>

     <div id="2" onclick="displayFunction(this.id)" class="projectTitel">
        <h1>Project: b</h1>
     </div>
  <div id="projectInhoudTwee" class="projectInhoud"> content </div>

     <div id="3" onclick="displayFunction(this.id)" class="projectTitel">
        <h1>Project: c</h1>
     </div>
  <div id="projectInhoudDrie" class="projectInhoud"> content </div>
```

Comment: use [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName), you need just to use a classname instead of the id name :)

Comment: Provide your `HTML`

Answer (score 1):

By combining [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) and [EventTarget.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), you can attach the same event handler to your divs. Inside this handler, you can retrieve the element you clicked on with the `event` object, provided by the event listener.

**EDIT** : The HTML you provided makes things a little more complicated because the `projectTitel` and `projectInhoud` divs aren't related to each other, except by position. 
So, in order to display the right `projectInhoud` div, we need to find the next `projectInhoud` after the `projectTitel` that was clicked on.

- To make things better, I would suggest editing the HTML to make `projectTitel` and `projectInhoud` divs children of a same parent div.
- Meanwhile, I added a `getClickedProjectIndex` function returns the index of the clicked  `projectTitel` div. And the click event uses this index to show the right `projectInhoud`.
- Then, you can use a simple `toggle` function that displays the div if it's not visible or hide it if it's visible.

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("projectTitel");

[...divs].forEach(someDiv => someDiv.addEventListener("click", handler));

// by default, all projectInHound are hidden
hideElements("projectInhoud");


function handler(event) {
    // get the clicked project's index :
    var projectIndex = getClickedProjectIndex(event);

    // toggle the right projectInhoud div :
    toggleDiv(document.getElementsByClassName("projectInhoud")[projectIndex]);
}

// hide all elements that have the provided class name
function hideElements(className) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

    [...elements].forEach(element => element.style.display = "none");
}

function getClickedProjectIndex(event) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("projectTitel");
    var projectIndex = 0;

    [...elements].forEach((element, index) => {
        if (element.id == event.currentTarget.id) {
            projectIndex = index;
        }
    });

    return projectIndex;
}

function toggleDiv(element) {

   if (element.style.display === 'none') {
      element.style.display = 'block';
   } else {
      element.style.display = 'none';
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="1" class="projectTitel">
        <h1>Project: a</h1>
     </div>
  <div id="projectInhoudEen" class="projectInhoud" > content a</div>

     <div id="2" class="projectTitel">
        <h1>Project: b</h1>
     </div>
  <div id="projectInhoudTwee" class="projectInhoud"> content b</div>

     <div id="3" class="projectTitel">
        <h1>Project: c</h1>
     </div>
  <div id="projectInhoudDrie" class="projectInhoud"> content c</div>
```

Comment: This hides the other divs, I made a mistake not including my HTML sorry for that. Look at my question again.

Comment: You edited the HTML wrong. Content div is outside the project div and its hidden by default. If you click on project A, the first div content should open (others 
 content divs closed) and so on.

Comment: @Blank  I edited. Does the snippet have the expected behaviour now?

Comment: It does as expected but the only thing is, it hides the other project divs (A B C)

Comment: @Blank Alright. I didn't understand this is what you wanted. See my last edit. It should work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this in the HTML:

```
<div class=myDiv onclick=myFunction(this)></div>
<div class=myDiv onclick=myFunction(this)></div>
<div class=myDiv onclick=myFunction(this)></div>
```

And for your JavaScript:

```
function myFunction(element){

    if(element.style.display = "none"){
        element.style.display = "block";
    else{
        element.style.display = "none";
    }

}
```